# SwiftUI: TextField in NavigationView Can't be editable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I defined the following swiftui's code:

```
struct RegistrationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var registerViewModel: RegistrationViewModel
    var withPassword: Bool
    
    init(withPassword: Bool) {
        registerViewModel = RegistrationViewModel(withPassword)
        self.withPassword = withPassword
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                FormTextField(value: self.$registerViewModel.name, placeHolder: "Name")
                    .frame(height: 75.0)
                FormTextField(value: self.$registerViewModel.email, placeHolder: "Email")
                    .frame(height: 75.0)
                DatePicker("Birthdate", selection: self.$registerViewModel.birthdate, displayedComponents: .date)
                    .frame(height: 50.0)
                    .padding()
                if self.withPassword {
                    PasswordFormTextField(value: self.$registerViewModel.password, placeHolder: "Password")
                        .frame(height: 75.0)
                }
                FormButton(title: "Register", action: {
                    self.registerViewModel.register()
                }, enabled: {
                    self.registerViewModel.validateRegistration()
                }).frame(height: 50.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 32.0)
            }
            
            .navigationBarTitle(
                Text("Register")
            )
        }
        
    }
}
```

The formTextField is the following:

```
struct FormTextField: View {
    
    @Binding var value: String
    var placeHolder: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8.0)
                .stroke(Color.black,lineWidth: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            TextField(placeHolder, text: $value)
                .padding(5)
                .font(Font.custom(Constants.regularFont, size: 18.0))
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```

However, I can't edit those textfield and I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

Maybe It is the navigation, maybe it is the View Herarchy.

PD: This it can works if I remove the NavigationView tag

Best Regards

Comment: What is FormTextField? If you use custom types you need to provide everything needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: FormTextField is a custom TextField, I will edit that

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem was the enabling button because it takes more than 5 seconds. So the solutions is the following:

```
FormButton(title: "Register", action: {
                    if self.registerViewModel.validateRegistration() {
                        self.registerViewModel.register()
                    }
                }, enabled: {
                    true
//                    self.registerViewModel.validateRegistration()
                }).frame(height: 50.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 32.0)
```